# emberjs menu component bubbling

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I have a menu component, which build a tree menu from an array.
To toggle the sub menus I do:

```
  didInsertElement:function(){
    this.$('li.sub').click(function(e){
      $('ul', this).slideToggle();
    });
  }
```

I works fine as long as I click on 'Settings'. If I try to click one of the sub menus ex. 'Currency' It closes the parent menu item.

Here is a jsBin to demonstrate the problem:
Click on 'Settings' -> then click one of the opened sub items:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bexivuhohu/6/edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is the parent component is still handling the click - even when clicking on a child component.

I would recommend moving the `click` handling to the component, rather than jQuery - and returning `false`. If the child component returns `false` the parent component doesn't double handle the click.

```
click: function() {
  this.$('ul').slideToggle();
  return false;
}
```

See this working JSBin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/bibeho/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: great but it wont work with menus with more items: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/suxapulaje/1/edit (all of the submenus open at once)

Comment: Ok here is the solution if anyone interrested: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/suxapulaje/2/edit  but jmurphyau's explanation about 'return false' solved the most of the problem.

Comment: I would have two components - a menu and a menu item... The menu item is responsible for expanding it's child menu - so you have a more direct link between the <li> for the menu item and it's child <ul>.. I think it creates a clearer separation between the elements and makes handling events and state easier

Comment: yes i thought about it as i started, but i decided to have it all in one component. Maybe I will rewrite it later.